# Highlighting roads in Google using Excel sheet of Roads

Tags: javascript, google-maps, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3

I would like to highlight all roads on a google map based on a csv,excel,fusion file - which would hold only road names. I realise it would prob need to have a more local identifier such as town.

I thought about finding the start and end number of the road but I couldn't seem to find a way of doing that and then possibly creating a trip or something.

It would also be nice if I could colour a subset of the roads in a different colour say if I put a 1 in for red and a 2 in for blue in the CSV.

C# or JS welcome :) any ideas welcome but whatever I get is most welcome :)

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not supported by the Google Maps API v3.